# Recursive case-class: java.lang.StackOverflowError on equals

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am playing with the exercises of *Functional programming in Scala* and implemented a simple singly-linked list.

Here is the relevant implementation part:

```scala
sealed trait List[+T]

case class Cons[+T](t: T, ts: List[T]) extends List[T]
case object Empty extends List[Nothing]
```

I built a "very big" list (hidden goal is to implement a tail-recursive `foldRight`):

```scala
def mkBigListOfInt(start: Int, end: Int) = (start to end).foldRight(workshop.List[Int]()) {
  case (item, acc) => Cons(item, acc)
}

val veryBigList = mkBigListOfInt(1, 1000000)
```

The issue comes when I try to compare the list with another (eg. using Scalatest DSL):

```scala
mkBigListOfInt(1, 1000000) shouldBe mkBigListOfInt(1, 1000000)
```

I get:

```
[error] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error]     at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.equals(BoxesRunTime.java:123)
[error]     at workshop.Cons.equals(list.scala:81)
[error]     at workshop.Cons.equals(list.scala:81)
...
```

(line 81 is the line I defined the `Cons` case class)

What would be a good way to implement `Cons` to allow comparing equality?

Since this is as an exercise, it is OK for me to keep it simple and incomplete (provided the trade-offs are spotted), so a "basic" solution is fine for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of case class `equals` is naively recursive. You can implement your own tail recursive version in `List`. Here's a start:

```
sealed trait List[+T] {
  override def equals(o: Object): boolean = o match {
    case ls: List[_] => equalsRec(ls)
    case _ => false
  }

  @tailrec
  def equalsRec(ls: List[_]): boolean = ???
```